# Why am I having errors while installing Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, conda

I had issues with my Tensorflow and had to re-install it. In order to ensure I do not make mistakes like I have done before, I followed Jeff Heaton tutorials (available [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RgO8BBNGB8w)) for installing Tensorflow for CPU. However, on executing the command: conda env create -v -f tensorflow.yml, I get some massive error (please see details [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l0tb7u03xmaqnvo/conda%20error.docx?dl=0)!).
Kindly show me where I am getting it wrong.

I have tried both 2020 and 2019 versions of anaconda. Using Miniconda did not help either.
Thank you very much.

Comment: `some massive error` actually means completely nothing. Be more precise

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski, the error report is about 4 pages and that is why I had to include it as an attachment. Thanks.

Comment: As docx? Really? Also, in most cases only first few lines are usable, other are just result of snowball failure, so you could paste at least this

Comment: Alright Marcin, I have noted this. I just felt the details could help you guys diagnose my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Please keep your question as self-contained as possible. Are you trying to install Tensorflow and the other packages to follow that specific course, or were you just using it as a reference?

Comment: @AMC, I am trying to install Tensorflow and other packages to follow that particular course. Like I mentioned earlier, I was follow the steps in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RgO8BBNGB8w&t=1s. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Follow the installation instructions on [Anaconda's website](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/tensorflow/) for TensorFlow for CPU:

```
conda create -n tensorflow_env tensorflow
conda activate tensorflow_env
```

Answer (score -1):

Pls, retry with anaconda

I hope it helps and to you

1. > > Download the latest version of anaconda, and start "Anaconda promt(anaconda)", then write this in Anaconda terminal
2. > > pip install tensorflow
   > >     And for test
3. > > python3
4. > > import tensorflow
   > >     If you haven't got errors, You succefully install library.

Comment: I do not understand point 2. Secondly, would I just enter python3 at the Anaconda terminal? Thanks

Comment: @Dean Yes, but if you didn't rename .exe file of python, you need write in terminal ```python```

Comment: If they're using Conda, installing a library with pip, especially Tensorflow of all things, should be a last resort.